# chef irb does not see files under system directory

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

On windows server 2008, when I run `chef\embedded\bin\irb` and type

```
File.exist?("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ServerManagerCmd.exe")
or
File.exists?("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ServerManagerCmd.exe")
or
File.exist?("C:/Windows/System32/ServerManagerCmd.exe")
```

I receive false, even though it exists and the terminal is run as administrator.
also if I try to run a dos command, it says that the file does not exist:

```
C:/Windows/System32/ServerManagerCmd.exe -version
```

I've noticed that when I tried other files:

```
File.exist?("C:\\Windows\\System32\\services.msc")
File.exist?("C:\\Windows\\System32\\SessEnv.dll")
```

these return true.
I compared the permissions; they are identical.
Does anyone have any suggestion how to debug and perhaps do a workaround?

Comment: Aside from the obvious - does that file actually exist?

Comment: yes. It does. As a workaround, I copied the file to C:\chef\cache and used it from there, but someone needs to fix chef before I lose my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like it's a problem with [64-bit (WOW64) redirection](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/02c7df62-0e29-46e1-9b57-b9fdf76ca091/cant-run-local-program).

You should be able to use the `sysnative` directory though. Try using this instead:

`File.exists?(File.join(ENV["windir"], "sysnative", "ServerManagerCmd.exe"))`

Comment: That's right. Chef runs as a 32 bit process on a 64 bit windows and this specific file is invisible to 32 bit apps. Thanks.